# Could anyone tell me why float can't hold 3153600000?

Tags: c++, c, overflow

I know this is stupid but I'm a quiet a noob in a programming world here is my code.

This one works perfectly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    float x = 3153600000 ;

    printf("%f", x);

    return 0;
}
```

But this one has a problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    float x = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 100 ;

    printf("%f", x);

    return 0;
}
```

So 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 100  is 3153600000 right ??? if yes then why does it produced different results ??? I got the overflow in the second one it printed "-1141367296.000000" as a result. Could anyone tell me why ?

Comment: That's what happens when you try to measure a year in centiseconds.  Turn the warning level of your compiler to eleven thousand centiclicks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're multiplying integers, then putting the result in a float. By that time, it has already overflowed.

Try `float x = 60.0f * 60.0f * 24.0f * 365.0f * 100.0f;`. You should get the result you want.

Comment: The `f` is not necessary (it's fine to do `double` arithmetic and store it in a float). The compiler likes doing this kind of stuff in `double` anyway. (At least GCC does.)

Comment: @greyfade: There are occasions where it matters.  They're fairly esoteric, but they do exist.  (Luckily, this is not one of them.)

Comment: @greyfade: Oh, and if the compiler does the constant folding in `double` anyway, then it's broken...

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: I agree, but in this case, the expression will probably be computed by the compiler, making it more or less a non-issue. :P

Comment: @greyfade: Yeah, I was referring specifically to constants computed by the compiler.  Sometimes it matters...

Answer (score 5):

`60` is an integer, as are `24`, `365`, and `100`. Therefore, the entire expression `60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 100` is carried out using integer arithmetic (the compiler evaluates the expression before it sees what type of variable you're assigning it into).

In a typical 32-bit architecture, a signed integer can only hold values up to 2,147,483,647. So the value would get truncated to 32 bits *before* it gets assigned into your `float` variable.

If you tell the compiler to use floating-point arithmetic, e.g. by tacking `f` onto the first value to make it float, then you'll get the expected result. (A float times an int is a float, so the float propagates to the entire expression.) E.g.:

```
float x = 60f * 60 * 24 * 365 * 100;
```

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't your compiler spit this warning? Mine does:

> warning: integer overflow in
>   expression

The overflow occurs before the all-integer expression is converted to a float before being stored in x. Add a .0f to all numbers in the expression to make them floats.

Comment: That only happens if the compiler executes the expression at compile-time.

Comment: Why wouldn't the compiler compute that at compile time?

Answer (score 1):

If you multiply two integers, the result will be an integer too.

`60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 100` is an integer.

Since integers can go up to `2^31-1` (`2147483647`) such values overflows and becomes `-1141367296`, which is only then converted to float.

Try multiplying float numbers, instead of integral ones.